# Lucene Query client

Tags: lucene

Can I run advance query using Lucene?
Advance Queries like facet query, multiple OR,AND query.

Comment: [RTFM](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/queryparsersyntax.html)

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed out by Kane, Lucene supports many of the operations described in your questions. If you need all of them you should have a look at lucene implementations such as Solr. Solr supports all of them and is baced on lucene.

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/

Answer (score 0):

Lucene can perform many of the operations described in your question (AND, OR, etc). Have you read the documentation or checked out sample applications? Depending on your needs you might want to look at RavenDB.